# Возможно ли обработать письмо в sh скриптом в postfix?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Возможно ли обработать скриптом sh входящее письмо?(скрипт будет вызываться при получении нового письма, сервер postfix) например поменять вложение, добавить текст в сообщение и доставить до получателя?

Comment: наверняка можно, в конце концов sh полный по Тьюрингу язык. Только зачем это делать именно на sh, если на многих других языках с использованием готовых библиотек работы с MIME это делается раз в 100 проще. И что вы понимаете под "доставить до получателя" вы хотите реализовать на sh собственный MTA ?

Comment: Имел виду обработать и отправить через sendmail. На чем будет проще выполнить подобный запрос, на python или perl?, или на чем то другом?

Comment: думаю на том, что более знакомо. хотя надо рассмотреть существующие библиотеки для работы с mime на сколько легко они позволяют выполнять требуемое